# How to activate the venv automatically while running the command prompt in the desired directory?

Tags: python, python-venv

I am currently learning Pandas and I want to open the `venv` again and again using the `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` command in the cmd.

I am usually using the `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` command but I need to automate my stuff

Comment: Use an IDE that supports virtual environments

Answer (score 0):

Using python from the command line, I usually create a batch file for initialising the environment which can be used from scripts etc. I have attached a simplified version of this script below. I normally use anaconda to manage my environments so it isn't exactly what you need, but hopefully it is close enough to adapt.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0

set py-env=virtual_environment_name
set "py-env-path=%userprofile%\Anaconda3\envs\%py-env%"

if not exist %py-env-path% echo Error python environment %py-env% does not exist && pause && exit /b 1

set "PYTHONPATH=%CD%"

cd /d %userprofile%\Anaconda3\Scripts
call activate "%py-env-path%"

popd
```